# Call multiple files using pylab

Tags: javascript, python, c++, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose I have 100 files with names `a0001, a0002, a0003, ..., a0100`. I have to call these files one by one.

Suppose I call `a0001` first and then perform some calculations and get two values as `b1` and `c1`. Then I call `a0002` and calculate `b2` and `c2` and like this `a0100` to calculate `b100` and `c100`.

Now I need to plot all 'b' and 'c' values on x- and y- axis (100 values for each). I need some help to form a loop so that I can call all files and store the calculated value to a plot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Abolfazl. I have posted the script. In this script I calculate c1 and Re for each file  from a_00001 to a_00454 and then I want to plot these values.

Comment: Formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help, usually, people provide some code then a more specific answer is possible.

```
filenames = ["a"+str("%04d"%i) for i in range(1,101)]
a = []
b = []
for filei in filenames:
    data = np.loadtxt(filei) # read each file
    # ...do some calculation
    temp_a = ...
    temp_b = ...
    a.append(temp_a)
    b.append(temp_b)

plt.plot(a,b)
```

Comment: Thank you Abolfazl for your response. It was really helpful.